# When a preposition comes consecutively!

Tags: prepositions

It did not seem meaningful for me when I saw a special usage of preposition *to* within a context. For example:

> Based on the performance scores in Phase I and the optimal number of stakeholders to be utilized in Phase II, the optimal routing of material from selected suppliers **to** manufacturers **to** warehouses were identified.

Is it OK for *to* to come twice almost consecutively? If so, then what does the last part of the above text (...from selected to...to...) mean?

Comment: Some similar sentences from the web: *"Peiper has stated that his regiment's route lay from Scheid to Losheim to Losheimergraben to Huenningen to Honsfeld."* *"From the George Washington Bridge take Route 4 west to Route 208 north to Interstate 287 south to Exit 58 in Oakland."* *"We are contemplating an automated routing of documents from A to B to C to D, [...]."* I think it should be fine. The last example also demonstrates the usage nicely. It's about the route (or routing) from A to B to C to D.

Answer (score 2):

It talks about the 'chain'. From A to B to C and so on.

As far as the usage is concerned, we certainly use prepositions in that way.

You don't need to go from *here to there to every corner* of the world to get an answer! :)